# How do I post code in a question I ask on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, markdown

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Please tell me how do I post a question effectively in this website.

I read the FAQ but I couldn't understand properly.
I would like paste my code in the thread so I usually put my code in the code block `[code][
/code]` but it's not working.

Please tell me how can I do this.

Comment: Found the solution. select the code and click on the curly braces on top. Very simple. Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a blank line above and below your code and indent the code by four spaces, and it will be formatted as code. You can create inline code (like `this`) by using backticks (like `this`).

Comment: And you can escape \` with \\`.